# How to use angular 6 in ionic 3?

Tags: angular, ionic3, ionic-native

I have an Ionic 3 app on Angular 5.2. I am trying to update to angular 6. I followed the upgrade guide already for the `HttpClient`and `NgModule`. The problem I have now is with the `ionic-native`.

I installed `ionic-native` V5 which is using `rxjs` v6 (required by angular6 and incompatible with previous versions).

Here is my `app.module.ts` file

```
import { Device } from '@ionic-native/device/ngx';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular'
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp
  ],
  providers: [
    Device
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I am getting multiple errors

> Cannot find name 'Device'
>
> Argument of type '{ declarations: (typeof MyApp)[]; imports: (ModuleWithProviders | typeof HttpClientModule | typeo...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NgModule'.
>     Types of property 'providers' are incompatible.
>       Type '(DeviceOriginal ' is not assignable to type 'Provider[]'.
>         Type 'DeviceOriginal' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.
>           Type 'DeviceOriginal' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.
>             Type 'DeviceOriginal' is not assignable to type 'ClassProvider'.
>               Property 'provide' is missing in type 'DeviceOriginal'.

The question is: Can ionic 3 work with angular 6 already?

Comment: Seems like your import is incorrect https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/device/#usage, could you try to change it to `import { Device } from '@ionic-native/device';`

Comment: Thanks, but actually, this is how to import should be done for v5. please see this https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/tree/v5

Answer (score 4):

So far, the only thing worked for me was keeping `ionic-native` to version `4.10.0` and also installed `rxjs-compat`.

I think it is too early to move further. Here is the `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": ">=6.0.9",
    "@angular/compiler": ">=6.0.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": ">=6.0.9",
    "@angular/core": ">=6.0.9",
    "@angular/forms": ">=6.0.9",
    "@angular/http": ">=6.0.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": ">=6.0.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": ">=6.0.9",
    "@angular/pwa": ">=0.6.8",
    "@angular/service-worker": ">=6.0.9",
    "@ionic-native/core": ">=4.10.0",
    "ionic-angular": ">=3.9.2",
    "purify-css": ">=1.2.5",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.2",
    "rxjs-compat": ">=6.2.2",
    "zone.js": ">=0.8.26"
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Like a post on the Ionic forums suggests, Ionic 3.x is not tested with Angular 6.x and therefore not officially supported.

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/upgrading-to-angular-6/131121/5

Better to wait and update to Ionic 4.x in my opinion.